# reset bone to use bone constraint

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

I want to use the bone constraint "copy transform" to a bone,but when a set a target the bone change position,rotation is all mess up without i move the target.
I apply the location and rotation of the target,clear pose but still...what i can reset to change this? [image]

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly + could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: here 
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51129
,sorry the blend-exchange file seen to load forever and its only 5mb,its  a simple test of the copy transform to bone,i just want that the bone dont twist when the target object is in the original position.

Answer (score 0):

The *Copy Transforms* constraint forces its owner to have the same transforms as its target (From the Blender manual page. ver_2.93).

This edit shows the following.
The value of the option *Target* is `target`, the value of *Impact* is `1` and the other values are as per 'image'.

Now, if you change the value of the option *Influence*  to`0` or the value of the type 'owner space space: custom space', the armature is supposed to be as above 'image'.